# Small question about the octahedron with regard to the diagonals.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Definition of an octahedron according to Wikipedia: "an octahedron is a polyhedron with eight [triangualar] faces".

Given are the points $A, B, C, D$ of an octahedron with equal edge lengths (picture). We also know that $ABCD$ is a square with center $M$. We call the remaining vertices $S_1$ and $S_2$.
Show that $\overline{AM} = \overline{MS_1}$.

There is a solution to this problem in which it is argued that the quadrilateral $AS_2CS_1$ is a square without giving a reason for this. Is this justified?

I do not want a proof of the statement. I just want to know if this statement is justified, since we only know from the octahedron in this problem that it has equal edge lengths and that $ABCD$ is a square, a justification should be given that $AS_2CS_1$ is also a square.

[image]

Comment: Has it already been justified why ABCD is a square?

Comment: No. That was more or less given. Since the coordinates of the points were given.

Comment: How are we supposed to know where the center of the octahedron is? If it is given that it is also the center of the square $ABCD$ then there is no need for a second square; simply show that triangles $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle S_1BD$ are congruent.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. That's my approach too. But the solution used the square and I think that's not a comprehensible starting point and wanted to ask for more opinions

Comment: @LineareLibelle: *"the coordinates of the points were given"* ... Please be clear about the starting info. ... Given the coords of the pts, it's easy enough to determine whether $ABCD$ is a square: eg, check that the sides are equal, and that two of adjacent sides make a right angle (or that the diags are equal, or, or, or, ...). ... Given only that the faces are equilateral triangles (ie, the figure is a *regular* octahedron), it *happens* that $ABCD$ is a square, but deducing this takes a little work. ... Given eight not-necessarily-equilateral triangles, all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

If $AS_2CS_1$ where an irregular rhombus, then the vertices connecting the shorter diagonal would be closer to $B$ and $D$ than the vertices connecting the longer diagonal, as the vector between them would have the same component normal to the plane but smaller component in the plane.

Comment: Since the task is intended for students and no strict mathematical justification is necessary, your justification would suffice for me. But do you think that your reasoning is necessary or is the starting point of the square justified?

Answer (score 0):

The statement is justified.

Very briefly: The symmetries of the octahedron allow certain rotations about the $AC$-axis that will leave it unchanged. Thus all angles of $AS_2CS_1$ are congruent, because they are brought to each other by these rotations. A rhombus whose angles are all equal is a square.

Comment: I understand your argument, but you are secretly replacing the definition I used with another one (I added the Wikipedia definition to make my starting point clear). Why can you argue with symmetry without having shown symmetry first?

Comment: The definition you give isn't sufficient to specify an octahedron. There are many polyhedra with eight faces.

Comment: The task adds that the edge lengths are equal.

Comment: And additionally, the question is not about whether there is a square, but whether a justification must be given.

Comment: A polyhedron with eight faces all of whose edges are equal could also describe a hexagonal prism.

Comment: The statement is justified if the shape is a regular octahedron. What information is given about the shape?

Comment: You are absolutely right. It should of course be about triangular faces.

Comment: All edges are of the same length. And ABCD is a square.

Comment: Given that ABCD is a square, four faces meet at $S_1$ and four at $S_2$. As none are shared this accounts for all faces. Two faces are common to $AS_1$ and two are common to $AS_2$, so four faces meet at A. If all the faces are equilateral triangles, it follows that the vertex figures are regular 4-gons. Thus $DS_1BS_2$ is a square. 
If it's presented as above, I don't think this really needs justification.